# How to remove double quotes from file while converting text to CSV?

Tags: linux, sed

**Problem:**

Using `cat` and `tr` commands I need to convert text file into csv format. But, as text file contains the double quotes in column value like  `" inch 2""`, so it will shift column values in next column.

**Solution tried:**

To convert text to csv used

```
cat SD_20190517053536.TXT | tr '\\t' ','   >  test.csv
```

command it will add duplicate column as next column instead of concatenating in one column header string.

Getting fields result using this above command:

[image]

but expected result should be column to their respective value :

[image]

Attaching sample text file:
[TEXT file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-nl7hjx_m2waI4FGFPPH5tHdiNg50UCSVFISNAGygM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The program that created the CSV file should have escaped the double quotes that aren't intended to quote the field.

Comment: Could you share some lines from the original text file? Is it just a csv file using tabs (`'\t'`) as delimiter and double quotes to quote fields containing special characters? IMHO, removing quotes from a csv file is weird... BTW tab character is a valid and common separator in csv files, only Excel does not like that...

Comment: Excel can read tab delimited .csv files. (The clue is that it can also export as tab-delimited) . I usually just name them as `.xls` and when you import them, you have to find the input prompt for field separator (not excel terms) and change it. It will also honor the dbl-quoted fields. Don't think I ever had to deal with `in.` = `"` however. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`.

```
sed "s/$(echo '\t')/,/g; s/\"/\\\"/g" SD_20190517053536.TXT > test.csv
```

Substitutes all the `\t` for `,` and the `"` for `\"`.